# Numpy function to get last element of 1-d array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-indexing

Given a numpy array `a`, is there any alternative to

```py
a[-1]
```

to get the last element?

The idea is to have some aggregating numpy method as

```py
np.last(a)
```

that could be passed to a function to operate on a numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np


def operate_on_array(a: np.array, np_method_name: str):
     method = getattr(np, np_method_name)
     return method(a)
```

This would work for methods such as `np.mean`, `np.sum` but I have not been able to find if there is some numpy method name that would return the last or first element of the array.

Comment: Can you provide use cases?

Answer (score 0):

What about a lambda?

```
lambda x: x[-1]
```

Comment: Can be assigned to `np.last` for OP `operate_on_array` to work. `np.last = lambda x: x[-1]` or `np.last = lambda x: np.take(x, -1)`.